# How to disable the "Chromium didn't shut down correctly" message? Chromium 17, Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, switch-statement, shutdown, chromium, kiosk

I am running Chromium in a kiosk-like environment and if the computer is powered off forcefully while Chromium is running, the next time it boots it will display the message "Chromium didn't shut down correctly. To reopen the pages you had open, click Restore."

I have tried saving some files within the ~/.config/chromium directory and replacing them before chromium loads but it doesnt seem to help. I cannot replace the entire folder as I need to keep things like local storage and cookies working normally.

I want to either HIDE this message from appearing, check for its existence and remove it, or prevent it being triggered in the first place.

Any advice?!

Comment: I resolved this by running the following command before launching chromium each time:  `sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`  source: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/WSK1J_Y_TvY (will update to answer later)

Comment: Why was my question down voted? I asked a question, but happened to figure it out the same day. It wouldnt let me post an answer so soon so I put it in the comments for anyone else that wanted to know. Am I missing something? Sorry, but I am new to stackoverflow...

Comment: M, apperently it was closed as "off topic" because the question is not really related to programming, the scope of the discussions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: you saved my day Daniel!

Comment: this should have been migrated to SU, not closed :(

Comment: To add to Daniel M.'s comment, under Ubuntu 14.04, I also needed a line: `sed -i 's/"exit_type": "Crashed"/"exit_type": "Normal"/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`

Comment: No spaces in that, sorry: `sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`

Comment: Also, apparently running in incognito mode by default will also prevent the error because nothing is saved from the session against which to check for a crash.